# postgresql and php why can't connect

Tags: php, postgresql

i want know how to call/connect postgresql data in php? because when i'm try to call it, in browser show this message error "Fatal error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\mydirectory\mymy\connectpg.php on line 2" . i'm using xampp 1.7.4 package and postgresql 9.2.6

Comment: I have tried to eliminate (;) in php.ini for ;extension = php_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll but nothing happen and in browsers still display an error message

Comment: have you restarted your apache?

Comment: yes i have restarted the apache but nothing happen ... and when i'm search in phpinfo() there's no pgsql...

Comment: have you save the file correctly?, is weird...

Comment: i'm sorry i'm new using database postgresql, i don't understand what file? the php.ini is save in C:\Program Files\xampp\php and my postgresql i install and save in directory C:\Program Files\xampp\

Comment: you should edit your php.ini file

Comment: i've edit the php.ini (i've removed (;) in extension=php_pgsql.dll and extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll) but nothing happen.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **php-pgsql** package or if you are in windows you need to activate the extension with same name **php-pgsql**

To activate it (I see that you are using xampp) you should add in your php.ini file (placed in `xampp\php`) the following lines (or uncomment it):

```
extension=php_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
```

Finally, you should restart the server

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
LoadFile "C:/yourphppath/libpq.dll"
```

to httpd.conf before loading php5 module